# This app is not compatible with this device iOS

Tags: ios

[image]When I update my iOS version from 9.3 to 9.3.1, then go to app store to install the app we get popup this app is not compatible with this device. Below is my screen shot.

[image]

Comment: What is the programming Question? Is this an app you made? Give more information.

Comment: Before 9.3.1 app is downloaded from app store. Is this thing is related to architecture in build setting of target.

Comment: I still don't understand what your question is, or if this is an app you developed or someone else's app.

Comment: I am developer of this app.

Comment: Can you give me suggestion how to fix this issue.

Comment: @NazishAli Yes it can be related to the architecture in build settings. Did you change the settings?

Comment: Hi I attached the build setting of my app. Please tell me what actually it should so that this thing could not happen in future .

Comment: What's the deployment target of this app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `NO` in `Build Active Architectures Only` Release configuration inside Build Settings.

**Edit:**

Here is an explanation why you need to set it as `NO`.

Setting this option to `YES` builds only for your device's architecture which is connected while building the app. It means if your connected device is a 64-bit device then this build will not work in iPhone 5 or older devices (32-bit).

Setting this option to `NO` will build a fat binary which will run on all architectures mentioned in `Valid Architectures` in build settings, thus allowing it to run on all devices.

Hope it clarifies your doubt. You can go ahead and release a new build with the correct setting.

JFYI you can also opt for an [expedite review](https://mobileroadie.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200091766-Requesting-Expedited-App-Review-on-iTunes) to make your update to get live faster. (Don't use it too much though).

Good luck!

Comment: Have you tested this issue, because it is urgent upload to app store.

Comment: Edited my answer with proper explanation. Have a look.

Comment: You want that for the *Release* configuration only; not *Debug*.

Comment: Yes that's right @trojanfoe. Forgot to mention that, edited my answer.

Comment: My pleasure, by the way nice app :)

Comment: I still have the same problem : / , what else can i do ? 

Itune's message:
"The app was not installed on the iphone because it is not compatible with this iphone"

Comment: @JorgeWanderSantanaUreña Are you sure you did the same for all of your major targets being used inside the app?

Comment: I think so, look at my issue details
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314672/xamarin-ios-ipa-iphone-app-is-not-compatible-installing-by-itune-on-mac

Comment: Also, there is a scheme that defines how the Archive build is created. You edit that scheme by selecting 'edit scheme' in the drop down menu that appears when you are picking which device to run on from Xcode. Under 'Archive' you should chose 'Distribution'.