# Xamarin IOS IPA iphone app is not compatible installing by itune from mac

Tags: ios, xamarin, bundle, itunes, setting

It is the typical error message from itunes app install telling me:

> "The app was not installed on the Iphone because it is not compatible with this iPhone"

I already have tried setting "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No", but without luck.

I can deploy and run the app from Xamarin in both Debug and Release mode without problem using my own device, but i can not install it when i generated an IPA from Xamarin.

I am sure that this is about a bundle setting because this was working before, but for some reason, it is not working any more : /

This is my current bundle setting
[image]

[image]

[image: Iphone device version-model]

Comment: What device are you trying to install on?

Comment: I am using IPhone 5s @Cheesebaron

Comment: Did you remove the app from the phone before trying to upload from iTunes? I remember once having a conflict due to still having the phone installed from another distribution platform...

Comment: Yes @Mark, i had removed it before try to install from itune

Answer (score 1):

**Done. this work for me:**

i removed arm64 and armv7s, setting armv7 only to get it works in iphone 5s.
And removed "Phone application." too from "Required device capabilities" key (this is important, because if i let it there, the problem persist)

[image]

Comment: It is strange because armv7 is not for iphone 5s according with these links:
[Xamarin Source](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/compiling_for_different_devices/#Architecture_Support), 
[Another Source](http://iossupportmatrix.com/)