# My app (developed in Cordova) is not getting downloaded on iOS 10.0.1

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

I deployed a hybrid app (Cordova) on iTunes App Store. Now its available for use. If I try to update the same app, I gets an error - on iOS 10.0.1 version - saying that:

"This app is not compatible with your device".

Any help would be really appreciable.

Thanks. :)

Comment: when you uploaded to appstore ?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37030356/1142743 in xcode and build in device you are testing

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be that you chose to build the architecture only for 64 bit devices; you did not include armv7.  This issue is discussed here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1910/_index.html

Also, there is a scheme that defines how the Archive build is created.  You edit that scheme by selecting 'edit scheme' in the drop down menu that appears when you are picking which device to run on from Xcode.  Under 'Archive' you should chose 'Distribution'.