# iOS - App build with Xcode 8 and iPhone 4S compatibility

Tags: ios, xcode

I build an app with Xcode 7 and minimum target 8. One of the clients was using iOS 9.2.1 on iPhone 4S. Then I updated the app (minor update) using Xcode 8 and keeping the exact same configuration. Now iPhone 4S user gets an error

> "app name" is not compatible with this iPhone

Any ideas why this is happening?
PS.(Valid architectures: arm7,arm7s,arm64)

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027960/this-app-is-not-compatible-with-this-device-ios